# Assigning a declared wire to connect ports on two different Verilog modules

Tags: verilog

I have a top level module that contains instances of other modules.

I simply want to connect the output of one module to the input of the other, like so:

```
module top_level(
...
);


module_a A(
  .out(my_wire)  // line 32
);

module_b B(
  .in(my_wire)
);

wire [7:0] my_wire; // line 51

endmodule
```

However, modelsim compiler is throwing an error that

> ** Error (suppressible): /../top_level.v(51): (vlog-2388) 'my_wire' already declared in this scope (top_level) at /../top_level(32)

I've tried removing the my_wire declaration (`wire [7:0] my_wire;`) and it compiles OK, but throws an error later because it infers my_wire to be a wire of size 1, when really a wire of size 8 is needed.

**What's the recommended way to do this?**

I've also tried:

```
module_a A(
  .out(in)
);
module_b B(
  .in()
);
```

but unfortunately I have other modules in top_level that have a port named `.in` which I don't want it connected to

---

I found this post
*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327819/output-of-a-module-used-as-input-of-another-in-verilog* but the solution didn't work for me.
I also saw this post *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286714/verilog-proper-way-of-connecting-ports* but found the answer a little confusing (sorry Oldfart, I have found your answers helpful in the past though)

Comment: What are on lines 32 and 51?

Comment: Post the code in your submodule.

Comment: To avoid inferring wire width as 1 bit, explicitly include the width: `module_a A(  .out(my_wire[7:0])  );  module_b B(  .in(my_wire[7:0])  );`

Comment: @dave_59 line 51 is `wire [7:0] my_wire` and and line 32 is the input port on B, `.in(my_wire)`

Comment: @MarkU just tried that. If I try that on both the the output port and input port, or just the input port alone, I get **Error: Undefined variable: 'my_wire'.** If I try it on just the output port I get **Illegal part-select expression for variable "alu_out"**

Comment: @JakeDaly I edited your question the way it should have been asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the order of the declaration in the reference. The error message is indicating they are in the reverse order of what you show. Wires must be declared before they are referenced. Otherwise they become implicit 1-bit wires and the the latter declaration becomes an error.